# sql script error on varchar and exit under mysql

Tags: mysql

This sql script gives me error at the `VARCHAR` and `EXIT;`. I try to run it under MySQL console. May I know how to solve this?

```
CREATE TABLE Solution (
SolutionKey    INT NOT NULL, /* PRIMARY KEY (SolutionKey), */
FeatureKey    VARCHAR(100),    /* +++ Foreign key missing here */
Value    VARCHAR(4000)
);


CREATE TABLE InactiveContext (
CaseKey    INT NOT NULL,     /* PRIMARY KEY (CaseKey), */
Context    VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE Class (
FeatureKey    VARCHAR(100),   /* +++ Foreign key missing here */
ClassName    VARCHAR(1000)
);


CREATE TABLE ExtraData (
Key    VARCHAR(1000),
Value    VARCHAR(1000),
FeatureKey   VARCHAR(100)    /* +++ Foreign key missing here */
);


CREATE TABLE ProblemCCBRFeatureSpec (
FeatureKey    VARCHAR(100),    /* +++ Foreign key missing here */
Question    VARCHAR(1000)
);


CREATE TABLE HashMap (
CollectionID    INT,       /* +++ Foreign key missing here */
Key    VARCHAR(1000),
Value    VARCHAR(1000)
);


CREATE TABLE HashSet (
CollectionID    INT,       /* +++ Foreign key missing here */
Value    VARCHAR(1000)
);


CREATE TABLE Constants (
ConstantName    VARCHAR(1000),    /* +++ Must be a primary key ??? */
ConstantValue    VARCHAR(4000)
);

COMMIT;
EXIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VALUE` and `KEY` are MySQL [**reserved words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) which you are using as column names.

To fix this you can either choose different names for these fields or you enclose them in back-ticks(**`**) *every time* you use them in the query.

```
CREATE TABLE ExtraData (
`Key`    VARCHAR(1000),
`Value`    VARCHAR(1000),
FeatureKey   VARCHAR(100)  
);
```

Later when you want to fetch data from the table you'll have to use quotes again as:

```
SELECT `Key`, `Value` from ExtraData;
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXIT'

Comment: You can remove the `EXIT` from the script.

Comment: No it does not, the end of the file is an implicit exit.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) for createing tables, such as

Key and Value,

Try to change this for others column Name

```
    CREATE TABLE ExtraData (Key    VARCHAR(1000),Value  
  VARCHAR(1000),FeatureKey   VARCHAR(100)  
  /* +++ Foreign key missing here */);
```